# Silently import a Certificate into a specific Certificate Store

Tags: certificate, x509certificate

I am attempting to import a Certificate into the Current User -> Personal store using the command line: `"importpfx -f [certificate name.p12] -p [password] -t USER -s Personal"`.

It works, but for reasons I don't understand there are now two Personal stores under the Current User, and the imported certificate is in the new Personal store.

When I try to connect to the website of [a well-known money transfer service], it fails. However, if I manually import the certificate using MMC into the original Personal store, it works.

My question is: How can I force IMPORTPFX to import the certificate into the original    Personal store, and how can I delete the new Personal store?

Context: 
I need to do a silent import of certificates on 3000+ remote point-of-sale Windows XP devices, so it needs to be a silent install via PSEXEC (SysInternals).

Thank you. Pieter.

Answer (score 1):

“Personal” is a just friendly name of the certificate store which is internally identified as `My`. You need to use

```
importpfx -f [certificate name.p12] -p [password] -t USER -s My
```